# Get direct ByteBuffer slice position relative to original ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio

Is there any way of getting a direct `ByteBuffer` zero position relative to another, given only the two `ByteBuffer` objects, if it is known that it is a subsequence of the other buffer?

I know that this can be done with a non-direct array backed `ByteBuffer` using the `arrayOffset()` method like so:

```
int getRelativeBufferOffset(ByteBuffer parentBuffer, ByteBuffer childBuffer)
{
  return childBuffer.arrayOffset() - parentBuffer.arrayOffset();
}

void example()
{
  ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);
  buffer1 .position(22);
  ByteBuffer buffer2 = buffer1.slice();
  buffer2.position(55);
  ByteBuffer buffer3 = buffer2.slice();

  // returns 22
  getRelativeBufferOffset(buffer1, buffer2);

  // returns 55
  getRelativeBufferOffset(buffer2, buffer3);

  // returns 77
  getRelativeBufferOffset(buffer1, buffer3);
}
```

I'm thinking that there isn't anything that exists for free for direct buffers. In order to get something similar the best option I can think of is to extend `ByteBuffer` to store a reference to the buffer from which it was created (the parent buffer) and the zero position relative to the parent's zero position at which it was created.

EDIT: Annoyingly it looks like I can't extend `ByteBuffer` because none of its constructors are visible. I guess I will have to write some kind of wrapper class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, using reflection. But depending on what you want to achieve, you should consider alternative solutions. It's not clear for which purpose you need this offset. The "pragmatic" recommendation would be to wrap the buffers into a simple, own class, like

```
class SlicedBuffer {
    int getBuffer() { ... }
    Buffer getParent() { ... }
    int getOffsetToParent() { ... }
}
```

and work with this one, but it's not clear whether this is applicable in your case.

I'll post the code using reflection here, but note that

```
// Many things...
// ... can go ...
// ... wrong when...
// ... using reflection
```

so this is only a demonstration:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class DirectByteBufferSliceOffsetsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testArray();
        testDirect();
    }

    private static void testArray()
    {
        System.out.println("Array: ");

        ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);
        buffer1.position(22);
        ByteBuffer buffer2 = buffer1.slice();
        buffer2.position(55);
        ByteBuffer buffer3 = buffer2.slice();

        // prints 22
        System.out.println(getRelativeBufferOffsetArray(buffer1, buffer2));

        // prints 55
        System.out.println(getRelativeBufferOffsetArray(buffer2, buffer3));

        // prints 77
        System.out.println(getRelativeBufferOffsetArray(buffer1, buffer3));
    }

    private static int getRelativeBufferOffsetArray(
        ByteBuffer parentBuffer, ByteBuffer childBuffer)
    {
        return childBuffer.arrayOffset() - parentBuffer.arrayOffset();
    }


    private static void testDirect()
    {
        System.out.println("Direct: ");

        ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(10000);
        buffer1.position(22);
        ByteBuffer buffer2 = buffer1.slice();
        buffer2.position(55);
        ByteBuffer buffer3 = buffer2.slice();

        // prints 22
        System.out.println(getRelativeBufferOffsetDirect(buffer1, buffer2));

        // prints 55
        System.out.println(getRelativeBufferOffsetDirect(buffer2, buffer3));

        // prints 77
        System.out.println(getRelativeBufferOffsetDirect(buffer1, buffer3));
    }

    private static int getRelativeBufferOffsetDirect(
        ByteBuffer parentBuffer, ByteBuffer childBuffer)
    {
        long parentAddress = getAddress(parentBuffer);
        long childAddress = getAddress(childBuffer);
        int offset = (int)(childAddress - parentAddress);
        return offset;
    }

    private static long getAddress(Buffer buffer)
    {
        Field f = null;
        try
        {
            f = Buffer.class.getDeclaredField("address");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            return f.getLong(buffer);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
        {
            // Many things...
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            // ... can go ...
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            // ... wrong when...
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            // ... using reflection
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (f != null)
            {
                f.setAccessible(false);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reflection solution is neat but for safety I think I am going to go down the wrapper route and encapsulate `ByteBuffer` in a `RelativeByteBuffer` class. Unfortunately `Buffer` doesn't expose the `duplicate()` and `slice()` methods so I can't do something neat like `RelativeBuffer<T extends Buffer>`.

Comment: The offset is for diagnostic logging purposes for when unexpected data is encountered in a buffer - I need to know the offset of the data relative to another buffer from which the buffer was created.

Comment: I think that for *solely* diagnostic purposes, the reflection solution should be fine. I'm not sure in how far the intention to perform such an analysis should affect how the classes are modeled in the first place. But in the end, the decision is up to you. And maybe someone else writes and answer that better suits your needs.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer because you have covered all bases here. Thank you for your help.